# fatfree custom routing do not work as expected

Tags: php, phpunit, fat-free-framework

As I am trying to writ unit tests in Fatfree framework with help of phpunit I am having issue with dependency injection. I am trying to pass the sql object into the constructor of the calling class, to make it work i tweaked the routing logic which is as follows:

routes.php

```
<?php

return array(
    "/index/something" => array(
        'class' => 'IndexController',
        'action' => 'index',
        'method' => 'GET',
        'requireDependency'=> 0,
        'mapper' => ''
    ),
    "/@action/@name" => array (
        'class' => "RandomController",
        'action' => 'index',
        'method' => 'GET',
        'requireDependency'=> 1,
        'mapper' => 'environment')
);
```

index.php

```
<?php

require('vendor/autoload.php');

// Retrieve instance of the framework
$f3=require('lib/base.php');

// Initialize
$f3->config('config/config.ini');

$configs = require 'config/routes.php';


/**
 * Dependency Injection for SQLMapper
 */

foreach ($configs as $url => $customParams) {

    $f3->mset(
        array(
            'class' =>  $customParams['class'],
            'action'=> $customParams['action'],
            'mapper'=> $customParams['mapper'],
            'requireDependency' => $customParams['requireDependency']
        )
    );


    $methodandUrl = $customParams['method']." ".$url;

    $f3->route(
        $methodandUrl,
        function ($f3, $params) {
            $sqlMapper = "";

            $class = $f3->get('class');
            $hasDependency = $f3->get('requireDependency');

            if($hasDependency) {
                $dependency = new DependencyController();
                $sqlMapper = $dependency->returnSQLMapper($f3);
            }

            if(!empty($sqlMapper))
                $object = new $class($f3, $sqlMapper);
            else
                $object = new $class($f3);

            if(empty ($params['action']))
                $action = $f3->get('action');
            else
                $action = $params['action'];

            call_user_func(array($object, $action), $f3);
        });
}

// Execute application
$f3->run();
```

IndexController.php

```
<?php
class IndexController {

    protected $db = "";

    public function index($f3) {
        $view=new View;
        echo $view->render('index.htm');
    }
}
```

RandomController.php

```
class RandomController {

    protected $className, $dp;

    public function __construct($f3,$dependency) {
        $this->className = $f3->get("PARAMS.name");
        $this->dp = $dependency;
    }

    public function index($f3) {
        $view=new View;
        $f3->set('name', $this->className);
        echo $view->render('template.htm');
    }

}
```

So when I run "index/something" it should call my index function, however it calls RandomController index function. I am not sure where I am going wrong, can anyone help me ?

**Update**

Or is there any other way where I can do dependency injection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue,

```
$f3->mset(
        array(
            'class' =>  $customParams['class'],
            'action'=> $customParams['action'],
            'mapper'=> $customParams['mapper'],
            'requireDependency' => $customParams['requireDependency']
        )
    );
```

as I was setting this in loop it would always call the last route, as it used to overwrite the previous one. So i moved this out side the loop as below

```
$f3->set('url', $configs);
```

This will hold the entire routes.php, and also changed

```
$urls = $f3->get('url');
foreach($urls as $url => $config){
                if($f3->build($url) == $params[0]){
                    $f3->mset(array(
                        'class' => $config['class'],
                        'action' => $config['action'],
                        'requireDependency' => $config['requireDependency'],
                        'mapper' => $config['mapper']
                    ));
                    break;
                }
            }
```

So not the class is exactly mapped to the URL entered.